# Deleting certain html blocks from HTML String - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a certain HTML string which roughly looks like follows :

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#a">a</a>
<a href="#5">5</a>
<a href="#4">4</a>
```

I want to write a generalized function that takes an integer as input. If, for example input = 2, the function should return an HTML string that is like this

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#a">a</a>
```

If input parameters = 3

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#a">a</a>
<a href="#5">5</a>
```

and so on. Any suggestions to how I can achieve this ?

Comment: No clue what you are expecting...

Comment: I hope I've elaborated the question good enough so that its easy to understand

Comment: Is your HTML in string form so this is a string manipulation exercise?  Or is it actually DOM elements in the web page and you want to get the first N DOM elements?

Comment: do you have those 4 links all the time? could there be more than 4 ?

Comment: @jfriend00 HTML in String variable

Comment: @Enjoyted Nope. That was just to make things clear. Ofcourse the no. of such <a> tags are not definite in my logic

Comment: If the HTML is just this simple, then just find the Nth "</a>" in the string and extract the string from beginning to that marker.

Comment: @RHLK - you haven't provided any feedback on any of these answers.  Did one of these answers meet your objectives?  If so, please mark it with a green checkmark as the best answer.  If not, please respond with a comment to answers to describe what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getFirst(amount, str) {

    return $(str).slice(0, amount);

}
```

Call like this:

```
getFirst(2, '<a href="#1">1</a>' +
'<a href="#a">a</a>' +
'<a href="#5">5</a>' +
'<a href="#4">4</a>')
```

Will result in:

```
<a href="#1">1</a><a href="#a">a</a>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/24h4Lykq/5/

Comment: Your function returns a jQuery object, not an HTML string and the jsFiddle doesn't appear to do anything (it reports an error in the console).

Comment: Fixed jsFiddle, it's true it doesn't return a String but I think he is going the put it in the DOM anyway and that makes this the most straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Making a few simplifying assumptions about the HTML (such as no embedded links within links and or `"</a>"` within HTML attributes), you can use code like this:

```
function getFirstNLinks(str, n) {
    var index = 0;
    var target = "</a>";
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        index = str.indexOf(target, index);
        if (index < 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // skip to end of match
            index += target.length;
        }
    }
    return str.slice(0, index);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5t8e964f/

---

You could also use the actual DOM parser and handle a wider variety of HTML, but that requires parsing into DOM elements, extracting a subset and then reconstituting the HTML from those DOM elements.

Here's a plain Javascript DOM parser implementation:

```
function getFirstNLinks(str, n) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.innerHTML = str;
    div.appendChild(div2);
    var links = div.querySelectorAll("div > a");
    // remove any excess links
    for (i = n; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].parentNode.removeChild(links[i]);
    }
    return div2.innerHTML;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/98qs2p9a/

---

If the end result is that you're going to put these links into the DOM, then doing string manipulation is probably not the right way to go about this.   Create the DOM elements form the raw HTML, then remove the excess links you don't want.  This lets the DOM parser do all the HTML parsing for you and you aren't convert to DOM, then back to string, then back to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function splitLinks(links, nbLinks){
        var links_a = links.split("</a>").slice(0, nbLinks);
        return links_a.join('</a>') + "</a>";
    }

    var str = '<a href="#1">1</a><a href="#a">a</a><a href="#5">5</a><a href="#4">4</a>';
    console.log(splitLinks(str, 2));

=> <a href="#1">1</a><a href="#a">a</a>
```

i try to make it simple =)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is overkill *(assuming **string** is your string)* DOMParser is the best method:

```
var result = [], num = 3,//ADJUST THIS NUMBER TO YOURS NEEDS
    doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<div>' + string + '</div>', "text/xml");
for (var i = 0; i < doc.firstChild.childElementCount; i += 1) { if (doc.firstChild.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1) { (i<num)&&result.push(doc.firstChild.childNodes[i]); } }
```

**Results are stored in the `results` variable**

#### jQuery?

The best part of this method is that it returns ***actual elements*** that you can use and modify. It will also work with any element type. It also uses plain JavaScript. An example is:

```
$(result[0]).attr('href');
```

works fine.

## Why?

That's a good question. If you are going to do *anything* besides splitting the strings. This is the best answer. For example, if the tags contained data, like in the `href` or another tag. This would perfectly for that.

#### As a string?

From what you said in your question, the most exact answer would be:

```
var stringresult = result.map(function(a){ var temp_parent = document.createElement('div'); temp_parent.appendChild(a); return temp_parent.innerHTML; }).join('\n');//Alternately use ' ' or '' in join
```

If you want an array, e.g. `[a href=​"#1">​1​</a>​, <a href=​"#a">​a​</a>​, <a href=​"#5">​5​</a>​]`

Use:

```
var arrayresult = result.map(function(a){ var temp_parent = document.createElement('div'); temp_parent.appendChild(a); return temp_parent.innerHTML; });
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2fqc6q5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery `$.parseHTML` and then include a parameter in your function for whether you want the result as an HTML string or an object:

*[Open the console to view the results from the snippet]*

```js
/// setup:

var str = '<a href="#1">1</a>' +
  '<a href="#a">a</a>' +
  '<a href="#5">5</a>' +
  '<a href="#4">4</a>',
  html = $.parseHTML(str);


var stringResult = getHTMLNodes(html, 0, 2, "string");
var objResult = getHTMLNodes(html, 3, 4, "object");

console.log(stringResult);
console.log(objResult);


/// function:
function getHTMLNodes(html, start, end, returnType) {
  
  // get the range of results:
  var sliceHTML = $(html).slice(start, end),
    result = "";

  // if HTML is specified
  if (returnType === "object") {
    return sliceHTML;
  } else if (returnType === "string") {
    sliceHTML.each(function(i) {
      result = result + $(this).prop('outerHTML');
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```